# Using a socket for a custom protocol over tcp

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, kotlin

My protocol looks like this:
`[size: UInt16][Channel: Uint16][Protobuff packet]`
The problem is, it is my understanding that tcp does not guarantee that an the entire packet as sent by the user will arrive all in one. Therefore, there could technically be a situation, where I don't get the entire message at once, or even that a part of another message is sent with this message.

It was quite easy, when I was just assuming that I would be getting the entire message at once, because I just read the first 2 bytes from the stream, made a buffer with the proper size and called `read(buffer)` however if I start thinking about the possibility of cut-off, I am not sure how to handle it. I tried the following:

```
    val input = clientSocket.getInputStream()
    while (!isStopped) {
        val bufferedInputStream: BufferedInputStream = BufferedInputStream(input)
        val dataInputStream: DataInputStream = DataInputStream(bufferedInputStream)
        var messageSize: Int? = null
        var channel: Int? = null
        while (true) {
            if (messageSize == null) {
                messageSize = dataInputStream.readUnsignedShort()
            }
            if (channel == null) {
                channel = dataInputStream.readUnsignedShort()
            }
            var bytesRead = 0
            var didReachEnd = false
            val buffer = ByteArray(messageSize - 4)
            while (bytesRead != -1 && bytesRead != messageSize) {
                val temp = dataInputStream.read(buffer)
                if (temp == -1) {
                    didReachEnd = true
                } else {
                    bytesRead += temp
                }
                Logger.debug(this::class.java, "bytes read: $bytesRead out of $messageSize")
            }
            val packet = ChatChannel.Packet.parseFrom(buffer)
            print(packet.chatMessage.messageText)
        }
    }
```

And I attempt to imitate a message splitting by doing the following from my client socket:

```
        val chatPacket = ChatChannel.Packet.newBuilder().setChatMessage(chatChannel).build()
        val sendPacket = Packet(0,chatPacket.toByteArray())
        val sendPacketByteArray = sendPacket.toByteArray()


        val halfPoint = sendPacketByteArray.size/2
        val firstSlice = sendPacketByteArray.sliceArray(IntRange(0,halfPoint))
        val secondSlice = sendPacketByteArray.sliceArray(IntRange(halfPoint,halfPoint+(halfPoint%2)))

        s.getOutputStream().write(firstSlice)
        sleep(200)
        s.getOutputStream().write(secondSlice)
```

however my implementation just hangs in the following line in the second time its ran:

```
bytesRead = dataInputStream.read(buffer,0,buffer.size)
```

I have a feeling I am missing some idea of how Sockets work, however every implementation I have seen, assumes that when the user is done sending he will close the connection, but in my case it's a chat program, so the user will only close the connection when were done chatting.

What I would like to achieve:

- read size
- read channel
- read bytes until the buffer of `size`  is full
- parse message
- notify
- back to step 0

Edit:
After further research, I found that MessageLite library to work with protobuf in Java seems to have methods called writeDelimitedTo(outputStream) and parseDelimitedFrom(inputStream) so it seems most of the work has been done for me.

Comment: `var bytesRead = 0`. That is not enough. You should add another variable like `var totalBytesRead = 0`. Then in the loop `if ( bytesRead!=-1)totalBytesRead+= bytesRead;`. Then compare totalBytesRead with messageSize to end the loop. Do not use bytesRead for that.

Comment: I fixed it, but the problem has nothing to do with it I suspect. The application just hangs the second time `dataInputStream.read(buffer)` is called, despite the second slice being written. It's like it doesn't listen to it

Comment: `val temp = dataInputStream.read(buffer,0,buffer.size)`. You should not always ask to read as many bytes as the size of the buffer. You made the buffer size equal to message size. Now if the message is 10.000 bytes you can ask to read 10000 bytes the first time. But if you get 3000 at the first read you should only ask for 7000 the next read. And so on. So ask for `messageSize-bytesRead`.

Comment: As you are messing around with message size and two two byte parameters it could well be that instead of `bytesRead != messageSize` you have to use `bytesRead != (messageSize-4)`.  Please elaborate what messageSize stands for. Your buffer is 4 bytes smaller then messageSize isnt it?

Comment: And i hate it that you did not introduce val totalBytesRead = 0; ;-)!

Comment: The value of messageSize should be the amount of bytes following your first two byte 'size' integer. Or the amount of bytes following those two values. Its up to you. Please explain what you choosed. If you have to extract 4 then thats not nice.

Comment: As Volker already tried to tell you: `val temp = dataInputStream.read(buffer+bytesRead,0,messageSize-bytesRead)`; Well for C that would do. In java you have to concatetenate the received bytes together untill you got the whole message. Or copy them to a totalBuffer.

Comment: No. Its easy. Change to `dataInputStream.read(buffer, bytesRead, messageSize-bytesRea‌​d);`.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

```
while (bytesRead != -1 && bytesRead != messageSize) {
                bytesRead = dataInputStream.read(buffer,0,buffer.size)
```

Seems strange to me. You do no increment bytesRead. That is, if messageSize is 100 and you read 90 bytes in the first read, you will read 10 bytes in the second read.
You cannot simply say  'bytesRead += ...' since it might return -1. So you need another variable. Check if the return value is non-negative and then do the increment to a byteCounter. This byteCounter needs to be compared to messageSize.

Also: If all you are doing is providing multiple channels for Google protobuf messages, don't do it like this! Create a protobuf message that contains the protobuf message and a channel variable. That should make life a lot easier.

Comment: I updated the code, to have another variable, but I am not sure my problem is related, since it is not my problem that the loop runs once too many, but that only the first part is read. As for the protobuf, I could put a channel on it, but then I wouldn't know to tell the difference between 3 kinds of messages that can be sent. The channel is used for both multiplexing and identifying the channel type, and therefore the message type

Comment: Look at nested messages. You would only send one message type that carries the "channel" variable and a nested message or that channel type.

Comment: I see what you mean :) I will probably do that then, though that still doesn't help my current issue :(

Comment: Another thing: you are confusing message size and payload size! Your while condition checks against the message size. However, you already consumed 4 bytes of header material. You need to initialize bytesRead with 4 or change your while condition.

Comment: You might want to check the specification of the read and ByteArray. Seems strange to write to offset 0 multiple times. You might need to replace 0 by bytesRead. In that case you need to initialize it with 0 and change your while condition to check against the payload size instead of the message size.